# Sqlite update a column based on where clause android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I am developing an android app, where I want to update a column in a row based on a where clause which comprises of two values. Below is what I have tried.

```
public void setlocationsetcolumn(double lats , double longs, String setvalue)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(Loc_set, setvalue);

    db.update(TABLE_LATLONG, values, " WHERE "+Loc_lati +" = " + lats+" AND "+Loc_longi+" = "+longs, null);
}
```

I wan to update the Loc_set, based on the lats & longs values. but i am getting a force close. Am I doing something wrong here. Please help.Thanks!

Comment: "force close" means that there's an uncaught exception. See the logcat for a helpful stack trace. In this case, at least the `WHERE` keyword should be omitted.

Comment: you should post the log

Answer (score 16, accepted):

below snippet will help you.

```
String[] args = new String[]{lats, longs};
db.update(TABLE_LATLONG, values, "Loc_lati=? AND Loc_longi=?", args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `WHERE` String . Try this :

```
db.update(TABLE_LATLONG, values, Loc_lati +" = " + lats+" AND "+Loc_longi+" = "+longs, null);
```

However, I Don't know what loc_lati and loc_longi are, hopefully columns in your db.

Comment: You should definitely go with the answer given by Vipul Shah, using the args as well.

Comment: Shouldn't use lats and longs string directly, because it can contains special character which will make SQL error. Let use args instead

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] args = new String[]{lats, longs};
db.update(TABLE_LATLONG, values, "Loc_lati=? AND Loc_longi=?", args);
```

You can use this logic for the update of table.